# Discord Bot Auto Deletes Https Links In certain Channels

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So This Code Is Meant To Delete Any Message That Includes `https`. So This Targets Links In Discord. However, I Want To Allow Links In 4 Channels (Channel ID is Below). But This Currently Just Deletes All https links no matter the server --- What Have I Done Wrong? or missed out?

```
if (message.content.includes("https")){
    var channelID = ["766716351007686697", "770229235788677161", "766720626471206942", "766720685723746314"]
    if (message.channel.id === channelID) return;

    const https = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    https.setTitle(`Deleted Message`)
    https.setDescription("Sorry But We Do Not Allow Links In That Channel");
    https.setTimestamp();

    message.author.send(https);

    message.delete()
```

No Error Message Comes Up

Comment: Can you put this in a `try{} catch(err){} ` and console.log(err)? What does it say?

Comment: @JonahG if i used this in the future, where would I add that in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`message.channel.id === channelID` always returns false because `channelID` is an array and `message.channel.id` is a string, which will never match. You're checking if `message.channel.id` exists in the `channelID` array, so the correct code to use for this would be:

```js
if (channelID.includes(message.channel.id)) return;
```

to check if `message.channel.id` is inside the `channelID` array.

Comment: Ah Okay, i didn't know that. cheers for the explanation aswell